# ADSL modem/router for varied desktop/server network topology

Tags: router, adsl

I'm currently running a hybrid home/office network comprising of several iPhones, laptops, and desktops (Windows, Mac), and gaming consoles - an average of 10+ devices connected at once. Vitally, I have a linux server which is publically exposed. The internet connection via ADSL2 with Annex M and a static IP.

I'm having major trouble finding a stable and well featured router. I've tried the router my ISP sent me (Thomson Speedtouch), which crashed several times daily. At the moment, I'm using a Netgear DG384N, which is more stable, but randomly turns off its wireless, really hates Vista laptops, and tends to lock up when the throughput is high.

What I need is

- Stability. I'm so tired of random failures
- Reasonable wireless range - The Wireless N feature of the Netgear has been useful
- A decent NAT, with UPNP (so it can support multiple XBox Live connections)
- Some form of DMZ, or at least robust port forwarding, so the server can be exposed on the static IP whilst stilling NATing.
- At least one ethernet port. Preferably 4+, gigabit (though I'm happy to get a separate wired router).
- ADSL 2/M support

I realise that's quite a lot, but has anyone come across a router that ticks at least most of these boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billion modems are very capable and will do everything you want. I run a 7404VGP-M at home in a similar configuration to that. It has only average wireless signal strength (802.11g) but is the closest thing you'll find to a 'Real' Cisco modem or a Linux box.
See www.billion.com .

Comment: Thanks - I finally got around to order a Billion 7800N that I'm hoping will perform well. gharper's answer is also great, but a bit out of my price range.

Also, now that Superuser's open, I guess this question should be migrated there?

Answer (score 1):

I've always had poor experience with all-in-one router/modem/wireless devices... it seems like the more features that get added, the lower the quality gets per feature.

It's more money and more devices to manage, but the best change I've ever made to my home network was to move to individual & dedicated devices.

- Cisco ASA5505 router
- Linksys WET610N wireless
- Netgear GS108 switch
- ISP provided modem

A problem with one device doesn't affect the others, and since they're isolated, it makes troubleshooting a heck of a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a number of ADSL Routers (Netgear, Thomson Speedtouch and Xyzel) but I have now changed to Linksys, as my broandbrand provider did give me a one of these Speedtouch boxes as it was the cheapest that supported ADSL2+.

The one I am using the now is a Linksys [WAG325N](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/UK/en/support/WAG325N). It does what it says on the tin, my son can plays his games all day and we not had to restart for weeks and the rest of use can surf without any issues

This does seem to get the best out of my connection as I can get up to 20mb down and 1mb up both Wired and Wireless and but this is because I can see my exchange. Not everyone is this lucky.

I assume the newer Linksys box [WRT320N](http://www.linksysbycisco.com/UK/en/products/WRT320N) would be just as good.